# compiler design and eliminating left recursion

Tags: compiler-construction, programming-languages, grammar

For example

```
E -> E+T | T
```

would be

```
E -> T E'
E' -> +T E' | null
```

If I have the production

```
B -> B == C | C
```

would these be the correct productions?

```
B -> C B'
B' -> ==C B' | null
```

another operator that I am having trouble with is '!', I know it has higher precedence than everything in my grammar except for "()" 
I came up with this but am not sure if it is correct.

```
T  -> U T'
T' -> *U T' | /U T' | null
U  -> ! ident | F
F  -> (A) | idlit | ftncall
ftncall -> ident(params)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think both are correct except in the second one you have to define `params` and `id-list` as well.

something like:

params -> id | id, params

In order to figure out if a grammar has a (ambiguous) left-recursion the easiest way is to feed the grammar to bison, parse generator and it will emit warning/error-message if the grammar is ambiguous.

As mentioned by @ibid, non-ambiguous left recursive grammars are parsed correctly by bison.
There are several online tutorials for that (To get started you can use: http://alumni.cs.ucr.edu/~lgao/teaching/bison.html)

Comment: Bison does not warn about left recursion – in fact, for Bison, you want to use left recursion where it naturally appears.

Comment: @ibid, I'm sorry I got confused by the ambiguous left-recursive grammar.